# Using Django's full text Postgresql search to match phrases

Tags: django

I'm using Django's [full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) successfully. However, I would like to match quoted phrases and can't see how to do this.

For example, I have a model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    search_document = SearchVectorField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(fields=['search_document'])
        ]
```

And I've done this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector

Article.objects.update(
    search_document=(
        SearchVector('title', weight='A') \
        + SearchVector('body', weight='B')
    )
)
```

But, if I do a search for:

> "tasty apples" fish

like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery

qs = Article(
        search_document=SearchQuery('"tasty apples" fish'))
```

then the results are the same as if I search for:

> tasty apples fish

i.e, articles that contain those three words, rather than articles that contain the phrase "tasty apples" and the word "fish".

Is it possible to search for phrases like this?

Answer (score 0):

Django's upcoming new release 2.2 will provide [a search type "phrase"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/#django-contrib-postgres).
You could look into how the SQL is generated in Django 2.2's [`SearchQuery` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/postgres/search.py#L147-L158) and backport it to your Django version if you are not able to upgrade any time soon.

A list of the functions for text search is available in the [Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-textsearch.html).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I *think* that means it can search for a phrase, but not a mixture of multiple phrases, or a phrase and a word, etc. I guess it'd be a case of using multiple `filter()` calls on the query, one for each phrase/word... Looks like 2.2 is due for release in a few days so I may give it a whirl (and report back).

Comment: You should be able to comibe multiple `SearchQuery` objects using `|` and `&` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchquery . Therefore you should be able to do something like `SearchQuery("tasty apples", search_type="phrase") & SearchQuery("fish")`.